# DCC-GARCH vs. EWMA vs. Historical Rolling Correlations - Which one to choose for historical correlation analysis?

Tags: time-series, correlation, garch, trend

If we want to calculate time varying correlation between various asset class (5 asset classes, each consisting of 10 indices) from 2005-2012 and if our purpose is not forecasting but analysis & inference based on historical data to look what the pattern is of correlation through time (constant, increase or decrease), then out of these  options which one is appropriate?

1. DCC-GARCH
2. EWMA
3. Historical correlations per subperiod

I possibly could use all three approaches and create various graphs, however this would create too much graphs which would make the report full of graphs, resulting in a unclear and unreadable report....

So what would the best approach be to make the report readable instead of having at least 150 graphs (5 asset classes * 3 methods * 10 indices) for all correlation coefficients?

Using approach 3, I could easily create correlation matrices per subperiod which also fixes the issue of having too much graphs. However, what should I do if I would like to use all three approaches, as for example the DCC-GARCH estimates correlation coefficients for each time t instead for a whole time period....

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Be aware that DCC does not allow for deterministic time trends in the correlation, so it is not suited for modelling increasing or decreasing correlation over time. You can supplement the model with an extra variable, a time trend in the equation for the conditional correlation, though, but I am not sure if this option is available in the software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one choose the preferred model based on a given modelling strategy. The choice of model may also depend on the required complexity for the problem at hand.

The models 1-3 are presented in the order from the most to the least complex.

1. [DCC-GARCH](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/13?topic=mdls): The model is a very commonly applied in the econometrics literature and will most likely be deemed adequate in most empirical application. However, due to the number of assets and indices, parameter proliferation may be an issue.
2. [EWMA](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/12?topic=mdls): A simple way of obtaining exponentially weighted correlation forecast. Will be less prone to parameter proliferation and may therefore be more practically applicable in this setting.
3. Historical correlation per sub-period: This is a method often applied by practitioners, if they want a quick idea of the historical evolution of correlation. You will however rarely see this approach applied in top level, econometrics papers.

Chapter 4 ("Forecasting High Dimensional Covariance Matrices") in "Handbook of Volatility Models and Their Applications" is one reference for comparing the different approaches in a high-dimensional setting.

Regarding your last question, then I would say that the whole idea of studying time varying correlation is to allow for a different correlation at each point in time. For the subsampling approach, you will e.g. calculate the correlation with the last T=1000 observations and have the estimate of correlation today. This could then graphically be compared with the DCC-GARCH estimates in the same graph.

Comment: DCC-GARCH avoids parameter proliferation by design as there are only 3 parameters in the DCC(1,1) equation and only $1+p+q$ in a DCC(p,q) equation for the conditional correlation, regardless of the number of assets in the system. This feature (besides computational simplicity) is perhaps the reason why DCC-GARCH is so popular in high-dimensional applications. So I think your characterization of DCC-GARCH needs a revision.

Comment: However, if everything is estimated jointly, then there are 50 GARCH models to estimate as well on top of the correlation parameters. It believe this to be somewhat tedious.  However, if only bivariate systems are considered, then I would personally apply multivariate GARCH models.

Comment: For most part, the estimation is no problem for me. The problem lies in the fact that if I would like to use at least 1 approach, it would result in at least 50 graphs.... And I honestly do not have any idea how to fix that..  50 to 150 graphs is too much for a  proper academic report, right?

Comment: We can easily perform the estimation, but the estimation uncertainty may be very high. As I understand, then your actual problem is how to properly graph your results. I think that you can plot many of the correlation "paths" in the same figure, then apply some clever labeling. Alternatively, I would just choose some representative correlation paths to display (e.g. one for each asset pair). Again, you may choose to plot it in the same figure.

Comment: @user3443027 and Johan, DCC typically uses stepwise estimation as the model design allows for that very naturally. First the individual GARCH models are fit, then the DCC part on top. The precise algorithm is described in the original paper by Engle. So indeed DCC is perfectly fit for high-dimensional systems. The ease of estimation is another major reason (perhaps the most important one) for why DCC is so popular.

Comment: I know, but you are still estimating a bunch of parameters. We have a straight forward algorithm for estimating the model, but I will still be worried about parameter uncertainty. Also, we need to invert a 50x50 matrix when copmuting the log likelihood, so I guess we may encounter problems. One reason for the introduction of equicorrelation models is the problems in the high dimensional setting.  A EWMA approach is probably more often used in the financial sector.

Comment: @JohanStaxJakobsen  , I think that the best way would be to use subperiods and thus estimate correlation matrices for those subperiods with each method. However, estimating EWMA and DCC garch would give me correlation coefficients/matrices for EACH time T instead of a whole subperiod as I would get with the historical correlation method

Comment: @JohanStaxJakobsen , Could I use the EWMA and DCC-GARCH in combination with the subsampling approach ?  If I estimate EWMA and DCC-GARCH, I get correlation matrices for each time T, so how could I get the correlation matrices for a whole subperiod?

Comment: @user3443027 A simple solution would be to just take the average over the correlations in a given subperiod. However, I still believe that this goes a bit against the spirit of time-varying correlation models.

Comment: @JohanStaxJakobsen, I do not quite get your argument. (I do not say you are necessarily wrong, but I do not understand your point.) You are not estimating a bunch of parameters at any given step. You estimate the univariate GARCH parameters (there are 3 for GARCH(1,1)) separately for each time series, so this is not a problem. You estimate the 3 DCC parameters after that. Where is the problem? Perhaps the matrix inversion argument might be valid (though DCC has worked just fine in practice in high dimensions before), but your claim *parameter proliferation may be an issue* is incorrect.

Comment: Also, please use @RichardHardy when addressing me, otherwise I do not get notified of your comments. Thank you. And of course, I am not saying DCC is the best model there is, but I try to stick to what the OP has listed for us. On a personal note, I have met Timo before and had a very nice chat. I hope he is a nice supervisor, and definitely there is much to learn from him :)

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes. He is a very nice supervisor. I will be having my PhD pre-defence (we work with a pre-defence and a public defence at Aarhus University) today.

Comment: @RichardHardy My thoughts on parameter proliferation are more in the lines that estimation errors in the first step estimation of all the volatilities will feed into the second step. Maybe I am wrong. But I agree that DCC-GARCH can be applied and that everything is simplified by the two step estimation procedure and that you have few parameters to estimate in each step.

Comment: Great! Then perhaps you could be more explicit in your point #1 to make this clear. And stop spending time on Cross Validated on your predefence day!! ;) Best of luck, though!